# Contagem de páginas da impressora Kyocera SNMP

Tags: ubuntu, snmp

Estou a tentar criar um `script` para inserir na base de dados as contagens da minha impressora.

Para criar um ficheiro com as contagens totais gerais utilizo as seguintes `OIDs` com as seguintes linhas de comando no ubuntu:

**Contador total**

```
snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.4.1.1
```

**Total cópias**

```
snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.3.1.1.1.1.2
```

...

**Total de impressão a preto**

```
snmpwalk -c public -v 1 192.168.0.123 1.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.3.1.2.1.1.1.1
```

Mas eu na minha impressora criei utilizadores e faço o controle de impressões e cópias mensal por utilizador.
Mas até ao momento, primeiro não sei se é possível aceder a essa informação por `script`, mas se for possível ainda não encontrei a `OID` para o fazer.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Votei para fechar a pergunta como fora do escopo porque não entendi a relação do problema com programação. Você cita o fato de estar criando um *script*, mas o problema parece estar centrado no comando executado. Se assim for, será mais fácil verificar a documentação do comando usando `man`. Se a pergunta é como executar esse comando através do seu *script*, não ficou suficientemente claro e sugeriria para [edit] e adicionar o código do *script*.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, então para utilizar esse comando da documentação, faço `man oip` ou `man mib`? Estou a perguntar porque não conheço esse comando

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, o problema é mesmo não saber qual é o OID para mostrar os utilizadores e a contagem de cada um. Não tenho problema com o script. Já pesquisei na internet e não encontro. Coloquei a questão, uma vez que na comunidade, poderá existir alguém que já tenha passado pela mesma dificuldade e já tenha conhecimento desse OID que procuro e não encontro.

Comment: Acho que não vai ser mesmo possível inserir numa base de dados as contagens mensais por utilizador